# How to use Date Picker and update the date value inside the array adapter in android

Tags: android, android-datepicker

I have checkable listview in my app which displays person name and date, when I click list items, it will expand the view below the list item.

In that view I have seekbar and texview for age and date picker, now if I click on textview a datepicker dialog is opening.

My issue is I want to set the date to the textview after clicking the 'Set' button in the datepicker dialog and also I want to update this date value to my list item also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the value within the data source that backs your `ListView`, then call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on your `ListAdapter`.

Comment: we have ended up with a super poor performance with this approach

Comment: @Zortkun If you have performance issues with your listview have you posted a question elsewhere with a code example? This is the standard way to update a listview in android.

Comment: not yet @Tom. In my case, we are calling notifyDateSetChanged() on the change event of a DatePicker.. and as one can imagine, as we spin through dates, it makes a lot of calls. But i m not sure if that s the only problem, i ll check and ask maybe

Comment: @Zortkun it does get slow when you have a listview with a lot of different data elements in it... It gets hackier when you keep references the individual views instead of updating the whole list but you can do it that way... just be careful that the views are still there when you try to manipulate them and that you're manipulating the right view, since the ListView recycles them.. can cause a bug REAL fast trying to do it this way. Honestly it's better to change the UX and put less stuff in the ListView. Have less views to change by using Spannables instead of several TextViews for example